# Show address on tap of marker in google map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have added google map in my app.I am showing current location on google map.I show a red marker on my current location now on tap of marker i want show the address above marker in a popup like which we normally see in apps.I have tried some the ways but none of them worked for me.sharing the code here.

1.First Way i tried

```
  @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mMap.clear();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        MarkerOptions mo=new MarkerOptions();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        marker=mMap.addMarker(mo.position(latLng));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        mo.title("Current Location");



    }
```

2.Second Way i tried

```
   mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
                String title = "Any Thing You want";
                marker.setTitle(title);

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Please tell where i am mistaken here.Thanks

Comment: What was your issue? What happens when you attempt these methods?

Answer (score 7):

Use Geocoder

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this,Locale.getDefault());
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(marker.getPosition().latitude(), marker.getPosition().longitude(), 1); //1 num of possible location returned
            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); //0 to obtain first possible address 
            String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
            String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
            //create your custom title
            String title = address +"-"+city+"-"+state;
            marker.setTitle(title);
            marker.showInfoWindow();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [Geocoding and Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

> **Geocoding** is the process of converting addresses (like "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739), which you can use to place markers on a map, or position the map.
>
> [**Reverse Geocoding (Address Lookup)**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding) - The term geocoding generally refers to translating a human-readable address into a location on a map. The process of doing the opposite, translating a location on the map into a human-readable address, is known as reverse geocoding.

Try

- [Google maps reverse geocoding via HTTPS in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635287/google-maps-reverse-geocoding-via-https-in-android) (This one needs a server key)
- [Displaying a Location Address](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html)

Also check this [tutorial about Google Maps on android](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/using-google-maps-android).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
 googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                String title = "Any Thing You want";
                marker.setTitle(title);
                marker.showInfoWindow();

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple

just add a title to it...

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(12.9969284, 80.25792380000007)).title("A2B Car Parking").icon(
            BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeResource(getResources(),
                            R.drawable.red_icon))).anchor(0.5f, 1f));
```

Hope this works!